# Max stack in python - 2 stacks solution

Tags: python

I am trying to build a max stack in python, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the question>

> Design a max stack data structure that supports the stack operations
> and supports finding the stack's maximum element.
>
> Implement the MaxStack class:
>
> - MaxStack() Initializes the stack object.
> - void push(int x) Pushes    element x onto the stack.
> - int pop() Removes the element on top of the    stack and returns it.
> - int top() Gets the element on the top of the    stack without    removing it.
> - int peekMax() Retrieves the maximum    element in the stack without    removing it.
> - int popMax() Retrieves the    maximum element in the stack and    removes it.
> - If there is more than    one maximum element, only remove the    top-most one.

```py
class MaxStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.stack_max = []

    def push(self, x: int) -> None:
        self.stack.append(x)
        if not self.stack_max or x > self.stack_max[-1][0]:
            self.stack_max.append([x, 1])
        elif x == self.stack_max[-1][0]:
            self.stack_max[-1][1] += 1
        else:
            self.stack_max.append(self.stack_max[-1])

    def pop(self) -> int:
        if not self.stack_max or self.stack:
            return
        if self.stack_max[-1][0] == self.stack[-1]:
            self.stack_max[-1][1] -= 1
        if self.stack_max[-1][1] == 0:
            del self.stack_max[-1]
        return self.stack.pop()

    def top(self) -> int:
        return self.stack[-1]

    def peekMax(self) -> int:
        if self.stack_max:
            return self.stack_max[-1][0]

    def popMax(self) -> int:
        if self.stack_max:
            return self.stack_max.pop()[0]
```

Example code:

```py
obj = MaxStack()
obj.push(6)
param_2 = obj.pop()
param_3 = obj.top()
param_4 = obj.peekMax()
param_5 = obj.popMax()
```

Input :

```
["MaxStack","push","push","push","top","popMax","top","peekMax","pop","top"] [[],[5],[1],[5],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Output:

```
[null,null,null,null,5,5,5,5,None,5]
```

Expected:

```
[null,null,null,null,5,5,1,5,1,5]
```

Reference: Leetcode 716. Max Stack

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your program, observe how each statement affects the variables, identify the point where these values differ from expected values, and go from there.

Comment: Check out: [Leetcode MaxStack in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210914/leetcode-maxstack-in-python). Any reason you have self.stack_max as a list rather than the current max value?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: @DarrylG that solution actually returned wrong output. The reason I use a list is to keep track of multiple maximum values. For example, [0,9,9,9], then with a list I can keep track. I will try using just a number.

Comment: Assuming you actually did need to track multiple maximum values, for some reason, you could use a dictionary rather than a list

Comment: And overall, [`queue.LifoQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) would work far better as a stack, than a list

Answer (score 1):

```
class MaxStack:
def __init__(self,value):#taking some value to avoid empty obj
    self.stack=[value]
    self.max_=[value,0]
    self.length=1
def push(self,value):
    self.stack.append(value)
    self.length+=1
    if value>self.max_[0]:
        self.max_[0],self.max_[1]=value,self.length-1
def pop(self):
    if self.length==0:
        return 
    elif self.stack[-1]==self.max_[0]:
        self.popMax()
    else:
        self.stack.pop()
        self.length-=1
def top(self):
    print(self.stack[-1])
def peekMax(self):
    print(self.max_[0])
def popMax(self):
    if self.length==0 or self.max_[1]==-1:
         return
    self.stack.pop(self.max_[1])
    self.length-=1
    self.max_[0],self.max_[1]=-1,-1
    for i in range(self.length):
        if self.stack[i]>self.max_[0]:
            self.max_[0],self.max_[1] = self.stack[i],i
```

Sorry for the improper indentations, I tried a lot to fix it. Anyways this should work and I wanted to try it out on leetcode but it needs a login. Let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems a little confusing to track the count in the tuple of the value, when you could just continue adding to the max stack and counting them from the list if you need that.

```
class MaxStack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.maxes = []

    def push(self, n):
        self.stack.append(n)
        if not self.maxes or n >= max(self.maxes):
            self.maxes.append(n)
    
    def pop(self):
        if self.stack:
            val = self.stack.pop()
            if val in self.maxes:
                self.maxes.remove(val)

    def top(self):
        if self.stack:
            return self.stack[-1]
    
    def peek_max(self):
        if self.maxes:
            return self.maxes[-1]
        
    def pop_max(self):
        if self.maxes:
            return self.maxes.pop()
```

Then if you need the count of the number of each, just use count():

```
def max_count(self):
    if self.maxes:
        return self.maxes.count(max(self.maxes))
```

Comment: but then say it push 123443 your algo will have maxes = [1,2,3,4,4] then when it pop 3 times the pop_max should be output the 3 that you didn't insert because 4 is higher.